# Creating a matrix from lists in NetLogo

Tags: list, matrix, netlogo

I'm using NetLogo to model viral infection in a population. Infected individuals are red and they also store a numerical value to represent the viral strain with which they're infected. I wanted to make a matrix that, for every timestep, stores the strain label of ONLY the infected individuals in the population (and potentially uses some placeholder for uninfected ones).

I have 100 individuals in my population and each simulation runs for 365 timesteps, so I know the matrix would have 100 columns and 365 rows – I just don't know how to translate this into NetLogo syntax. For example:

```
  to track-strain-diversity
    report list ([tflu-strain] of turtles with [color = red])

 how do I store this list as a row for a single timestep in a matrix?
 how do I then fill in each subsequent row with the flu strains found in each timestep?
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out the [matrix extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/matrix.html) if you're hoping to use indexing to access some of the values, or if you want to do some matrix math in the model after you've collected your strain info. If you want to go this route, check out the [`matrix:set-row`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/matrix.html#matrix:set-row) primitive from that extension.

If you're just recording these values then outputting them for analysis elsewhere, you may be satisfied just using a list of lists to store the strains each tick, then outputting that list of lists at the end using the [csv extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/csv.html).

Example following uses this setup:

```
extensions [ csv ]
globals [ strains strain_list_list ]
turtles-own [ infected? flu-strain ]

to setup
  ca
  set strains [  1 2 3 ]
  crt 5 [
    ifelse random 2 = 0 [
      set infected? true
      set flu-strain one-of strains
    ] [
      set infected? false
    ]
  ]
  set strain_list_list ( list t-sorted-strain-list )
  print strain_list_list
  reset-ticks
end
```

With this option, you'd still need to have some kind of placeholder as you mention, so that your rows are all the same length. You could make a reporter to do so, something like:

```
to-report my-strain ; turtle reporter
  ifelse infected? [
    report flu-strain
  ] [
    report 0
  ]  
end
```

That reporter (called by a turtle) reports that turtles flu strain number if it has one, or zero if it doesn't. For tidiness, you could have that reported as a list sorted by the turtles so that each "column" corresponds to a single turtle:

```
to-report t-sorted-strain-list
  report map [ i -> [flu-strain] of i ]  sort turtles
end
```

Then it's just a matter of running your model and recording that `t-sorted-strain-list` as a new entry in the list of lists (`strain-list-list`). When your model has run all the way through, you can output that entire list of lists as a csv file for analysis using `csv:to-file`. In this example, the model will `go` until all turtles are infected at which point the model will output `strain_list_list` to a csv file called "strains_each_tick.csv" then the model will `stop`.

```
to go
  if not any? turtles with [ not infected? ] [
    csv:to-file "strains_each_tick.csv" strain_list_list
    stop
  ]
  ask turtles with [ not infected? ] [
    if random 5 = 0 [
      set flu-strain one-of strains 
      set infected? true
    ]
  ]
  set strain_list_list lput t-sorted-strain-list strain_list_list
  tick
end
```

That output file loaded into R looks something like:

```
> df
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  2  0  0  3  2
2  2  0  0  3  2
3  2  0  2  3  2
4  2  0  2  3  2
5  2  3  2  3  2
```